# sum up prior values of rows in a new variable in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable that is the sum cumulatively of the rows in the "pop" variable and is the cumulative total. I am trying to use the rollsumr function to replicate the output that is represented by the "cumulative_pop" variable in the sample data, but I am unclear on how to specify k = all the prior rows (i.e., all rows up until the current row). Advice?

```
data.frame <- data.frame(pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                         cumulative_pop = c(1, 3, 6, 10, 15))

library(zoo)
data.frame$pop_sum <- rollsumr(data.frame$cumulative.pop, k = , fill = NA)
```

Comment: `data.frame$pop_sum <- cumsum(data.frame$pop)`

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the cumulative sum using `cumsum`. For example,

```
df <- data.frame(pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                         cumulative_pop = c(1, 3, 6, 10, 15))
library(dplyr)
dplyr::mutate(df,cumulative_pop2=cumsum(pop))
```

Answer (score 1):

Same with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397695/rollsumr-with-window-length1-filling-missing-values), you can fill use `rollsumr` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

# Your initial data frame
data.frame <- data.frame(pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                         cumulative_pop = c(1, 3, 6, 10, 15))

data.frame%>%  
  mutate(pop_sum = rollsumr(pop , k=nrow(data.frame), fill = NA), 
         pop_sum = ifelse(is.na(pop_sum), cumsum(pop), pop_sum ))
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Based on documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf#page=49&zoom=100,132,89):

> k = integer width of the rolling window.

And this `rollsumr` only have final output (as the name suggests sum) per call

If you force to use `rollsumr` without `cumsum` like code above, you can use looping. Here is the sample code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

# Your initial data frame
data.frame <- data.frame(pop = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                         cumulative_pop = c(1, 3, 6, 10, 15))

data.frame$pop_sum<- NA  # Create an empty column

for (i in 1:nrow(data.frame)) {
  data.frame$pop_sum[i] <- sum(data.frame$pop[1:i])
}

data.frame
```

The output will be same as above